# How to read the Azure Web job log files using C#

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have around 10 jobs running in azure daily basis, so I need a total report of the jobs. For this I need to read logs using C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can list all web jobs using the following API first, and then you can get logs from `log_url` of each webjob.

```
GET /api/webjobs
```

For detailed information, please check [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API).